# PHP threads on Non-thread safe WIndows PHP

Tags: php, multithreading

Is it possible to use pthreads pecl package (or something similar) on Non-thread safe windows version of PHP (accessed through fast CGI wrapper)? The requirements for pthreads  state the ZTS must be enabled, so i was wondering if there was an workaround or some completely different solution.

Comment: You could try a custom compile of php on windows to enable the threadsafe compile flags however I think its a limitation of the windows scheduler/php code that it can't be compiled to thread safe. You're probably better off running up a VM running linux and either running all code on there or just running phpfpm and then telling your php/webserver (nginx,cherokee,lighttpd as I'm not sure if apache or IIS on windows supports that) on windows to use the unix machine for php processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pthreads will not work without ZTS in the PHP library; there is no workaround, nor should there be: ZTS - Zend Thread Safety ... only a madman wants threads that are unsafe !

Comment: This answer has been reviewed by a moderator, and deemed to be an answer to the question.  It hasn't been evaluated for correctness.  If anyone has anything to add, post a new answer or leave a comment to that effect.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. +1.